# Question on orthogonal subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm given a problem with the initial values 
$u =\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} , v = \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}, b =\begin{bmatrix}4\\5\\6\end{bmatrix}$.

I've calculated that the projection of $b$ onto $span(u,v)$ is $\hat{b} = \begin{bmatrix}4\\5\\0\end{bmatrix}$, and that the error is $e = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\6\end{bmatrix}$, but I'm a bit weak on the material, and hopefully my answers to the problem below are correct.

[image]

(Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv0EX.png )
The subject of the second sentence isn't explicitly specified, but the previous question demonstrated that $e^Tu = 0$ and $e^Tv = 0$, so assuming that "this" refers to $q$, that would mean that $q = e$. My main question is with the second part: we haven't covered the left nullspace yet, but from Wikipedia is seems that $e$ satisfies this definition because it is orthogonal to both $u$ and $v$. Is this correct, or is it in the right nullspace instead?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed. You are correct: $e$ resides in the *left nullspace.*

See more here: [Four Fundamental Subspaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fundamental_subspaces), in the entry to the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Algebra.

Comment: I always hate it when posters do not acknowledge answers! +1

Comment: @Amzoti Yes, even if it's a quick comment: "okay, I get it" or a follow up question...

Comment: Agreed! Just so you even know they looked at it!